# Unable to run mongod: Fatal Assertion 28562

Tags: mongodb, installation

Newbie here learning node.js and mongodb. I am currently trying to install mongodb on my Mac and faced the following issue when i try to run mongod on terminal.

```
2016-01-31T12:08:39.791+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :    pid=13733 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Joshuas-MBP
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-31T12:08:39.792+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-31T12:08:39.794+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-01-31T12:08:47.249+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (22) [1454213327:242370][13733:0x7fff72b68000], WT_SESSION.create: 'table:_mdb_catalog' cannot be used until all column groups are created: Invalid argument
2016-01-31T12:08:47.259+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28562
2016-01-31T12:08:47.259+0800 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I have basically performed the following operations on terminal to install mongodb after looking through the docs and online tutorials:

```
joshuatan ~ $ brew update
joshuatan ~ $ brew install mongodb
joshuatan ~ $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
joshuatan ~ $ whoami
joshuatan
joshuatan ~ $ sudo chown joshuatan /data/db
joshuatan ~ $ mongod
```

I have been searching around in google/stackoverflow but am not able to find any posts which have encountered a similar error.

Am i missing something? Would really appreciate any help/guidance...Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've run Mongo previously as root, try `sudo chown -R joshuatan:joshuatan /data/db`

Comment: i get an illegal group name error as indicated: joshuatan ~ $ sudo chown -R joshuatan:joshuatan /data/db
chown: joshuatan: illegal group name

Comment: OK, just make it `joshuatan` instead of `joshuatan:joshuatan`

Comment: thanks but it still results in the same error though, did you go through similar steps for your installation?

Comment: Getting exactly same issue running as Docker container now. But happens quite randomly. 9 out of 10 containers run ok. Clueless so far. It seems the only common thing we have is major version (i'm at 3.2.8). Going to try with 3.4.x

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was (which was mac os)

```
rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.soccd; cd /data/db;  rm -rf *;
```

then just mongod to start it up

Comment: be careful with the steps, if you don't have /data/db, this command can delete your other files

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Catalina, like me, what seems to work is to create a properly placed `data/db` on `System/Volumes/Data/data/db`, with

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

And, then, add that path to `mongod.conf` (located on `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`), replacing `dbPath` there:

```
...
storage:
  dbPath: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
...
```

Then, restart it. If you are using brew, do:

```sh
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

Source: https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/